# Spring JPA: build a library that can implement a 'where' clause under the hood

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

Context: I am trying to create a small library that I can add to existing applications that have complex queries implemented already. I am hoping to be as non-invasive as possible, so a developer on these existing applications would only have to import the library itself, extend my custom repository, and add the tag that is supposed to be filtered upon into their applications.
Question: Is it possible to create a custom repository that extends everything JpaRepository gives and add a where on top of everything before execution. With the JPQL queries and named queries being included?

No code has been written, just looking at source code from [Spring Jpa](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/tree/main/spring-data-jpa/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa).
Looking at [JpaSpecifications and QueryDsl](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/), but would these be able to handle named queries?

Comment: Do you mean that your implementation would use normal `@Query` but before "moving down" to `JpaRepository` it would add said `WHERE` clause, correct?

Comment: Yes the application this library would be attached to would still be using the @Query and a later layer down the `WHERE` clause would be appended.